# Best way to integrate your Django project homepage

Tags: python, django

What would be considered the best practice for integrating your website's homepage in your Django project?

Should you make a new application, naming it "homepage" and place the view for it in there? Or is it considered a waste of space to create an entire application just for that? Or should you just stick it somewhere in one of your applications randomly? Or is there some other better option I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with the homepage, you're going to encounter other things that don't really fit into an application, such as shared utils, base templates, about page, contact page, etc.

For these things it's generally best to put them into an application that is general to the project, I name my general application "main".